# I am Using Zxing library for printer but got error while generating signed apk

Tags: android, android-studio

getting following error

**Warning:zj.com.customize.sdk.QRcode: can't find referenced class com.zj.command.sdk.Command
Warning:there were 8 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
Warning:Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'.

> Job failed, see logs for details**

Comment: I am Using Zxing library for printer but i'm generated signed apk getting error?

Comment: 0
down vote
favorite
Warning:zj.com.customize.sdk.QRcode: can't find referenced class com.zj.command.sdk.Command

Warning:there were 8 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.